# Most efficient datatype for iteratively adding to?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I have a web scraper which iteratively retrieves data from web pages, and I would like to add the attributes pulled to a pandas dataframe (eventually) for running simple statistics and analysis. The current script returns a dictionary every time a new page is scraped.

I understand adding a new row or column to an existing pandas dataframe is slow, so my thought was to add the dictionary's as they are retrieved to a csv, and then convert this csv all at once to a dataframe when the data collection is finished (possibly months from now). I will be dealing with up to 100,000 dicts, with 18 key value pairs.

Is there a more efficient method or datatype to use in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say `when the data collection is finished (possibly months from now)`. It is enormous amount of time in comparison with efficiency of python or pandas or any other programming tool I can imagine. I just created 100k random dictionaries of length 18 containing floats, saved them into text file (csv format) and loaded with pandas into dataframe. Took 2 seconds to save and 0.5 seconds to load. So just add every new record to the file and periodically create backups of your choice.